# nodejs - module dependencies

Tags: node.js, module

Let's say I have module A.js and B.js.

**A.js**

```
var b = require('./B');
[...some code here...]
```

**B.js**

```
var a = require('./A');
[...some code here...]
```

than in my **`app.js`** I have something like:

**app.js**

```
var a = require('./A');
[some code here]
```

The thing is that the `var a` in **`B.js`** is always an empty object **`{}`** when I do like **`node app.js`** while If I directly do **`node B.js`** it is properly initialized.

What instead I would expect is that calling **`node app.js`** it triggers **`A.js`** (that requires **`B.js`**) and so, in turn it initialtes its own **`a`** variable.... but it is not like this apparently....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a [circular module dependency](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_cycles), so the sequence goes like this:

1. `app.js` requires A
2. A requires B
3. B requires A (which is not completely defined yet)

In step 3, B gets the definition of A at the time of the require.  That's just an empty object at that point so that's what `a` gets set to in `B.js`.

Comment: yeha, I think so too... thanks for the link and the information.